# STM32439I-EVAL2 board problems with camera

Tags: camera, embedded, stm32

I am working with the STM32439I-EVAL2 board and my OV2640 camera is not functioning properly. I have been testing it with the MB1063 Demonstration example from the STM32CubeF4 software and when I try to use the camera it shows "Error while Initializing Camera Interface. Please, chech if the camera module is mounted" on the LCD daughter board, even though the camera module is mounted and connected to the board. Has anyone else had this problem and solved it?  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. If anyone else has this problem, put this code in STM32Cube_FW_F4_V1.1.0\Drivers\BSP\STM324x9I_EVAL\stm324x9i_eval_io.c

```
uint8_t BSP_IO_Init(void)
{
 uint8_t ret = IO_ERROR;

 /* Read ID and verify the IO expander is ready */
 if(stmpe1600_io_drv.ReadID(IO_I2C_ADDRESS) == STMPE1600_ID)
 {
 /* Initialize the IO driver structure */
 io_driver = &stmpe1600_io_drv;
 ret = IO_OK;
 }

 if(ret == IO_OK)
 {
 io_driver->Init(IO_I2C_ADDRESS);
 io_driver->Start(IO_I2C_ADDRESS, IO_PIN_ALL);
    io_driver->Config(IO_I2C_ADDRESS,IO_PIN_0,IO_MODE_OUTPUT);
    io_driver->Config(IO_I2C_ADDRESS,IO_PIN_2,IO_MODE_OUTPUT);
    io_driver->WritePin(IO_I2C_ADDRESS,IO_PIN_0,1);
    io_driver->WritePin(IO_I2C_ADDRESS,IO_PIN_2,0);

 }
 return ret;
 }
```